# Java XLM get Element by Name

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to read out a few lines from XML Files in my Java program.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<BiosCfg>
  <Menu name="Advanced">
    <Menu name="Boot Feature">
      <Setting name="Restore on AC Power Loss" selectedOption="Power On" type="Option">
        <Information>
          <AvailableOptions>
            <Option value="0">Power On</Option>
            <Option value="1">Stay Off</Option>
            <Option value="255">Last State</Option>
          </AvailableOptions>
          <DefaultOption>Power On</DefaultOption>
          <Help><![CDATA[Select the Restore on AC Power Loss function.]]></Help>
        </Information>
      </Setting>
    </Menu>
  </Menu>
</BiosCfg>
```

I've shortened this example to only contain the Element I want to read.
There are many different "Setting" Elements, but I would like to explicitly get the one that has "Restore on AC Power Loss" as its name.

I have tried doing this with Java's Document(BuilderFactory) classes, but haven't found a way to use their methods to achieve this.

What would be the best way to do this in Java?

Comment: why not parse it to a Java object and use a getter?

Comment: I never worked with xml, but u can try to use an xml parser. I hope this like will helps: https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml

Comment: @Stultuske unedited, this XML file has almost 5000 lines. If I understand correctly, I'd need to include every single Attribute in my Java Object so converting it would work.

Comment: @Korlimann, parses usually has the option to read the content directly, without mapping the xml to an object.

Comment: Doing this in plain DOM is a pain in the ******. You might want to check https://dom4j.github.io/#xpath

Comment: @KunLun thanks, but I am already trying to do this with a DOM Parser. Apologies, I should have declared that better in my post

Comment: @GyroGearless thank you, I'll take a look at it!

Comment: [Java API for XML Processing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

try using saxon xpath impl, nice and compact...

```
InputStream xml = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/in.xml");
Processor processor = new Processor(false);
String query = "//Setting[@name='Restore on AC Power Loss']/Information/AvailableOptions/Option/text()";
XdmNode xdm = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new StreamSource(xml));
XdmValue result = processor.newXPathCompiler().evaluate(query, xdm);
result.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

Output:

```
Power On
Stay Off
Last State
```

[Maven Saxon-HE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/10.5)